# Create account in EOS using RPC method or npm package

Tags: eosjs, wallet, rpc, account-creation

I wants to create account in EOS using RPC method or Npm package.As per review dev doc of EOS not found any methods for it. I am implementing this in nodejs.

Kindly guide for it, how can i process for EOS account create.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it out here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/master/docs/2.-Transaction-Examples.md#create-new-account-multiple-actions
Just follow the configuration.

Comment: thank you for help.